# Get error before retryWhen operator

Tags: angular, rxjs

I'm learning to use the `retryWhen` operator but I'm having a problem of getting the error when or before the `retryWhen` operator executes. This was my first code:

```
ngOnInit() {
  this.subs1 = this.rateService.getClpBtc()
    .subscribe(prices => {
      this.clpbtc = prices.ticker.min_ask[0];
    }, errors => {
      if (errors) {
        this.surbtcErrors = errors;
        console.log(`The name is: ${errors}`);
      }
      else {
        this.surbtcErrors = null;
      }
    });
}
```

This was working fine and I could get the error in the property named `surbtcErrors`. But then I added `.retryWhen(errors => errors.delay(5000))` right before the `subscribe` operator and I realized that even if there was an error, my property was empty because I believe the subscribe operator is not executing (I'm not sure, I'm learning).

So, after some research I tried this:

```
ngOnInit() {
  this.subs1 = this.rateService.getClpBtc().retryWhen(function(errors) {
    if (errors) {
      console.log(`Error: ${errors}`);
      errors.delay(5000);
      return this.surbtcErrors = errors;
    } else {
      console.log("SIN ERROR")
      return this.surbtcErrors = null;
    }
  })
  .subscribe(prices => {
    this.clpbtc = prices.ticker.min_ask[0];
  }, errors => {
    if (errors) {
      this.surbtcErrors = errors;
      console.log(`The name is: ${errors}`);
    } else {
      this.surbtcErrors = null;
    }
  });
}
```

With this code I'm getting `Error: [Object object]`. So, my question is how can I get the error so I can use it inside `surbtcErrors` property?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `errors` argument passed to your `retryWhen` function is an observable stream of errors.  This function is supposed to return an observable stream that indicates when to retry.  The example `errors => errors.delay(500)` basically says to just retry 500ms after any error.

You can use [do](http://reactivex.io/rxjs/class/es6/Observable.js~Observable.html#instance-method-do) to run a side effect when the error arrives.  In your case, the side effect is storing the error as a variable on your component.

To do this, we just insert a `.do(...)` clause before the `.delay`.  Like so:

```
this.rateService.getClpBtc()
  .retryWhen(errors => errors
               .do(error => this.subtcErrors = error)
               .delay(500));
```